# Pip skips a file from installation

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to deploy a new version of a project I've been working on. I zip the package into a .tar.gz file using the standard python `setup.py sdist` command, and then install the package using `python -m pip install x.tar.gz`.

All the files which are required are present in the archive itself (the .tar.gz file) but for some reason pip skips installing one of these, a binary file containing some lookup tables. Moreover, I think this happens only on linux (I make the package itself using Windows, and here everything works fine). I would think that this might have something to do with using `sdist` instead of `bdist`, but with previous versions I've had no issues of this kind, despite using the same method. I'm not sure if there is any architecture dependency at play here. Are all binary files architecture dependent?

Any ideas regarding what might be the cause of this?

Comment: Have a look at https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/#how-files-are-included-in-an-sdist -- You might need to add your file as `package_files`, `data_files` or you might need to add the file to a `MANIFEST.in`.

Comment: How is the file included by `sdist`? What does your `setup.py` look like?

Comment: I use the `include_package_data=True` argument in `setup.py`. The file is listed in my MANIFEST.in, and it is also present in the sdist distribtuion archive, but for some reason it is not installed. I'll try with the `package_files` vs `data_files`.

Comment: Is this file part of a package? Could you show the relevant parts of your project's directory tree, and the content of your `setup.py`?